# Leverage Spring boot Redis Auto configure logic for RedisConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache, lettuce

Spring boot auto configures `RedisConnectionFactory` if `spring-data-redis` exists on classpath and  `RedisConnectionFactory` is initialized in `LettuceConnectionConfiguration` if Lettuce-core available on classpath.

I've only one Redis store as of now, so leveraging Spring boot auto configuration.

Now I'm adding two redis stores, one redis store used as default and other is used when specified with parameter `cacheManager = "secondayCacheManager"` in `@Cacheable` annotation so, application should've capability to cache/cache-get on both redis stores.

To configure both Redis Stores, we've to configure both the primary and secondary `RedisConnectionFactory` and `cacheManager` using custom configuration. (because spring doesn't auto configure `RedisConnectionFactory` if it already exists in any custom configuration)

Now the above is custom configuration and missing lot of logic that is happening while configuring `RedisConnectionFactory` in `LettuceConnectionConfiguration`.

Auto configure logic for `LettuceConnectionConfiguration` is package private so, cannot be called directly from custom configuration.

> We would like to leverage the auto configure logic in
> `LettuceConnectionConfiguration` while configuring the custom
> `RedisConnectionFactory` for both primary and secondary redis caches.
> Is there a way to achieve this?

Reason being we would like keep the redis connection configurations as it is done by spring boot auto configure.

Currently using below code to configure both the primary and secondary `RedisConnectionFactory` with Pool configuration and some code copy pasted from `LettuceConnectionConfiguration` class.

```
public static LettuceConnectionFactory buildLettuceConnectionFactory(RedisProperties properties, ClientResources clientResources) {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(properties.getHost(), properties.getPort());
        standaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(properties.getDatabase());
        if (properties.getPassword() != null) {
            standaloneConfiguration.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(properties.getPassword()));
        }
        if (properties.getUsername() != null) {
            standaloneConfiguration.setUsername(properties.getUsername());
        }
        LettucePoolingClientConfiguration poolingClientConfiguration = LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
            .poolConfig(buildGenericObjectPoolConfig(properties))
            .shutdownTimeout(properties.getLettuce().getShutdownTimeout())
            .clientOptions(createClientOptions(properties))
            .clientResources(clientResources)
            .build();
        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(
            standaloneConfiguration, poolingClientConfiguration);
        lettuceConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    private static GenericObjectPoolConfig buildGenericObjectPoolConfig(RedisProperties properties) {
        RedisProperties.Pool pool = properties.getLettuce().getPool();
        GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        if (Objects.nonNull(pool)) {
            poolConfig.setMaxIdle(pool.getMaxIdle());
            poolConfig.setMinIdle(pool.getMinIdle());
            poolConfig.setMaxTotal(pool.getMaxActive());
            poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(pool.getMaxWait().toMillis());
        }
        return poolConfig;
    }

    private static ClientOptions createClientOptions(RedisProperties properties) {
        ClientOptions.Builder builder = initializeClientOptionsBuilder(properties);
        Duration connectTimeout = properties.getConnectTimeout();
        if (connectTimeout != null) {
            builder.socketOptions(SocketOptions.builder().connectTimeout(connectTimeout).build());
        }
        return builder.timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled()).build();
    }

    private static ClientOptions.Builder initializeClientOptionsBuilder(RedisProperties properties) {
        if (properties.getCluster() != null) {
            ClusterClientOptions.Builder builder = ClusterClientOptions.builder();
            Refresh refreshProperties = properties.getLettuce().getCluster().getRefresh();
            Builder refreshBuilder = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()
                .dynamicRefreshSources(refreshProperties.isDynamicRefreshSources());
            if (refreshProperties.getPeriod() != null) {
                refreshBuilder.enablePeriodicRefresh(refreshProperties.getPeriod());
            }
            if (refreshProperties.isAdaptive()) {
                refreshBuilder.enableAllAdaptiveRefreshTriggers();
            }
            return builder.topologyRefreshOptions(refreshBuilder.build());
        }
        return ClientOptions.builder();
    }
```

Comment: Raised the issue at spring-data-redis. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/2502